# Are there any limits around what you can edit in Palantir Foundry's Actions?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-for-ibm-cloudpak-for-data, foundry-actions

I would like to edit an existing Action in Palantir Foundry. Are there any limits around what you can edit in Actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Palantir Foundry's Actions, there are currently two limits in place to reduce data refresh time and ensure all tables are always up to date:

- Maximum of 1000 object edits in one action
- Maximum of 10 object tables edited at once